# What is the most compatible video player?

Tags: video

I have a number of videos that are each in WMV, MP4 and FLV format that I will be hosting.  I would like to embed a video player that, when activated, will automatically select and play a compatible version of the video. This means that the website visitor will not have to guess what format will work for them.

My initial search ended up with http://videojs.com/ but before I go and start tinkering here, I would like to hear any experience here?

The video player must work, without failure in IE6+, Safari 4+, Opera 10+, Google Chrome 7+ and Firefox 4+.

Comment: What do you mean by "most cross-browser compatible?" Most players bend over backwards to make things at least usable even in problem children like IE6, including your own example so you've kind of answered your own question. If that's not "most" enough for you already, more information is needed. It's generally better to define your requirements than ask for some arbitrary "best" that other people might define differently.

Comment: Noted, I hope that by making an edit and defining my browser requirements I am being more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recomend a look at JW Player http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/

There's free and 'Pro' paid for versions.